# Laravel update composer

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

I have a problem when I run `composer update`. I get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   Call to
>   undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event
>   returned with an error
>
> [RuntimeException]   Error Output:

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to solve it.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
    "riari/laravel-forum": "~3.0",
    "mcamara/laravel-localization": "1.1.*",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "2.*",
    "hootlex/laravel-friendships": "^1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
    "djb/confer": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Comment: This might help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/call-to-undefined-method-illuminatefoundationapplicationbindshared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the `illuminate/html` package? I have seen similar errors solved by removing this from your `composer.json`.

It would be helpful if you could post the entire `composer.json` file too.

Comment: i was first with the illuminate/html, but i have replaced it from the composer.json with the laravelcollective/html, but the error remains ?

Comment: i found the bindShared() error. The problem is maybe one new Package, which is using old methods, but now i have the following issue: FatalErrorException in Facade.php line 221:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::composer(). How should i replace it ?

Comment: If that's not related I'd suggest opening a new question to get more eyes on it as I'm not sure :)

Comment: To fix it .i executed `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload -o` in command prompt